# C# Excel Interop Unable to get Characters.Text property when Range length is > 256

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm trying to Bold specific characters in an Excel sheet using C# Excel interop library. I have the specific characters within curly braces {} and using this function to make them bold.

```
void FormatCharacters(Range r)
{
    Characters chars = r.Characters[0, r.Text.Length];
    if (chars.Text.Contains("{") && chars.Text.Contains("}"))
    {
        int startIndex = chars.Text.IndexOf("{");
        int len = chars.Text.IndexOf("}") - startIndex + 1;
        Characters bold = r.Characters[startIndex, len];
        bold.Font.Bold = true;
        bold.Text = bold.Text.Replace("{", "");
        bold.Text = bold.Text.Replace("}", "");
    }
    else
        return;
    FormatCharacters(r);
}
```

**The function works perfectly if the cell has text less than 256 characters.** When the cell has text greater than 256, I get the following exception:

*System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException*

*Message=Unable to get the Text property of the Characters class*

*ErrorCode=-2146827284*

**How do I overcome this 256 character limit in Excel Characters interface?**

**Any alternative approaches using interop?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't an issue with your code but more of a limitation with the Excel interop library.

Comment: Not sure is this is an intentional limitation, but you could process them in chunks of 256 just to get it working.

Comment: I've tried processing them in chunks, that is when I realized that the limitation is not on the character size we select, but rather the range length itself.

Comment: Other things I tried are avoid using the Characters.Text property and replace the '{', '}' characters using Range.Replace function. But when I do that, I lose the formatting in the entire cell !!